# How to shrink polygon using postgis?

Tags: postgis

I am using postgis 2.2, how can i shrink my polygon to 10 meters using postgis queries ?

This is my polygon

> POLYGON((72.89994120597838 19.070245311788284,72.89981782436371
>   19.069915760688904,72.9002845287323 19.070001951039718,72.9003381729126 19.070341641985888,72.89991974830626 19.07023517176424,72.89994120597838 19.070245311788284))

Comment: [What have you tried so far?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)
Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve] of the code
that you are having problems with, then we can try to help
with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [ST_Buffer](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_Buffer.html) function like this

```sql
SELECT ST_Buffer(
  ST_GeogFromText(
   'POLYGON((72.89994120597838 19.070245311788284,72.89981782436371 19.069915760688904, 72.9002845287323 19.070001951039718, 72.9003381729126 19.070341641985888,72.89991974830626 19.07023517176424, 72.89994120597838 19.070245311788284))'
  ), 
  -10
);
```

Note the **`-10`** at the end is the number of metres by which to shrink.